# Cryptic NDSolve::nlnum when working with matrices

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration, complex, quaternions

This problem was initially formulated in quaternions, but I had to rewrite them to complex matrices (as they seem to be supported better). Possibly introducing some errors along the way. So the construct "Im, Re, Im" turns those complex matrices into real vectors, and the construct "List[]==" is needed because I can't take an element of matrix inside NDSolve.

I will include two versions of the code, a full one for copyability, and the TeX for equations for readability.

```
Io={{1,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,2}}

NDSolve[{Λ[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{Ω1[t], Ω2[t]}, {Ω3[t], Ω4[t]}} == 2 ConjugateTranspose[Λ[t]].Λ'[t], ω[t] == {Im[Ω1[t]], Re[Ω2[t]], Im[Ω2[t]]}, ω[0] == {0, 1, 0}, {{P1[t], P2[t]}, {P3[t], P4[t]}} == {{0, I}, {I, 0}}.ConjugateTranspose[Λ[t]].{{I, 0}, {0, -I}}.Λ[t], Io.ω'[t] + Cross[ω[t], Io.ω[t]] == Re[P1[t]] {Im[P1[t]], Re[P2[t]], Im[P2[t]]}, Λ[t] == Conjugate[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}.Λ[t].{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}], Ω4[t] == Conjugate[Ω1[t]], Ω3[t] == -Conjugate[Ω2[t]], P4[t] == Conjugate[P1[t]], P3[t] == -Conjugate[P2[t]], Det[Λ[t]] == 1}, {Λ, Ω1, Ω2, Ω3, Ω4, ω, P1, P2, P3, P4}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

$$\small\eqalign{\Lambda[0] &== \{\{1, 0\}, \{0, 1\}\},\cr \{\{{\Omega}1[t], {\Omega}2[t]\}, \{{\Omega}3[t], {\Omega}4[t]\}\} &== 2\: ConjugateTranspose[\Lambda[t]].\Lambda'[t],\cr \omega[t] &== \{Im[{\Omega}1[t]], Re[{\Omega}2[t]], Im[{\Omega}2[t]]\},\cr \omega[0] &== \{0, 1, 0\},\cr \{\{P1[t], P2[t]\}, \{P3[t], P4[t]\}\} &== \{\{0, I\}, \{I, 0\}\}.ConjugateTranspose[\Lambda[t]].\{\{I, 0\}, \{0, -I\}\}.\Lambda[t],\cr Io.\omega'[t] + Cross[\omega[t], Io.\omega[t]] &== Re[P1[t]] \{Im[P1[t]], Re[P2[t]], Im[P2[t]]\},\cr \Lambda[t] &== Conjugate[\{\{0, 1\}, \{-1, 0\}\}.\Lambda[t].\{\{0, -1\}, \{1, 0\}\}],\cr {\Omega}4[t] &== Conjugate[{\Omega}1[t]],\cr {\Omega}3[t] &== -Conjugate[{\Omega}2[t]],\cr P4[t] &== Conjugate[P1[t]],\cr P3[t] &== -Conjugate[P2[t]],\cr Det[\Lambda[t]] &== 1}$$
The first six equations are physical, the last six are for consistency (and because Mathematica says "underdetermined" without them). And after all this, Mathematica says:

```
NDSolve::nlnum : The function value {1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 2. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 2., 0.}
 is not a list of numbers with dimensions {15} at {t, P1[t], P2[t], P3[t], P4[t], Λ[t], ω[t], Ω1[t], Ω2[t], Ω3[t], Ω4[t], P1'[t], P2'[t], P3'[t], P4'[t], Λ'[t], ω'[t], Ω1'[t], Ω2'[t], Ω3'[t], Ω4'[t]}
 = {0., 1., 1., 1., 1., {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}}, {0., 1., 0.}, 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, {0., 0., 0.}, 0., 0., 0., 0.}.
```

This is rather cryptic for me. I don't know what "function value" it talks about, but at least it contains only numbers (it contained language constructs before some fixing).

Comment: The length, if I counted right, is 23, not 15.  Sorry, I've got to go.  I expect the "function value" is the value of the right-hand side in the equivalent first-order formula tion of the ODE. No, probably not: It's a DAE, isn't it?

Comment: It's a DAE, that's right. Only two of 12 equations are differential, the second (angular speed from quaternion orientation) and the sixth (Euler's equation of rotation).

Comment: I will clarify that the question is still unanswered. An answer would be some hint as to how to get rid of the error.

Comment: You can get rid of "the" error with `Method -> {"DAEInitialization" -> {"Collocation", 
    "CollocationDirection" -> "Forward"}}`, but it doesn't get rid of all errors....

Comment: There seems to be a free parameter, at least at the initial condition, suggesting some conditions are redundant. That could be causing the trouble. (The error messages are not really helping, if this is the case. I'm pretty sure that analyzing nonlinear matrix equations will be done except via numerical solvers.  So it probably cannot deduce the redundancy. In that case it may help to replace your matrix variable with a 2x2 matrix of scalar variables; ditto for the vector variable.)

Comment: There seems to be some credence to your suggestion about a free parameter. I will have to look at it closely. But thanks a lot for the option setting. I would've guessed at it for ages.

Answer (score 2):

First, Mathematica really can't handle matrix (and vector) variables inside NDSolve. At least version 9.

Second, while this solution works in version 9, Mathematica 8 says "NDSolve::underdet". Seems to be a bug which has been fixed.

Third, it appears that you can take an element of a matrix inside NDSolve, if you enclose it inside Block.

So I:

1) Replaced Λ and ω with component lists.

2) Expressed Ω#s via ω#s (quaternion via vector) and threw Ω#s out.

3) Hid P#s inside a Block (and they became a single matrix value).

4) Hand-solved for Λ's and ω's.

5) Haven't checked the result, but this doesn't give any error messages in version 9.

That's it. You still have to hand-solve when  using Mathematica.

```
Io = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}
NDSolve[{{{Λ1'[t], Λ2'[t]}, {Λ3'[t], Λ4'[t]}} == 1/2 {{Λ1[t], Λ2[t]}, {Λ3[t], Λ4[t]}}.{{I ω1[t], ω2[t] + I ω3[t]}, {-ω2[t] + I ω3[t], -I ω1[t]}}, {ω1'[t], ω2'[t], ω3'[t]} == Inverse[Io].(Block[{P = {{0, I}, {I, 0}}.ConjugateTranspose[{{Λ1[t], Λ2[t]}, {Λ3[t], Λ4[t]}}].{{I, 0}, {0, -I}}.{{Λ1[t], Λ2[t]}, {Λ3[t], Λ4[t]}}}, Re[P[[1]][[1]]] {Im[P[[1]][[1]]], Re[P[[1]][[2]]], Im[P[[1]][[2]]]}] - Cross[{ω1[t], ω2[t], ω3[t]}, Io.{ω1[t], ω2[t], ω3[t]}]), {{Λ1[0], Λ2[0]}, {Λ3[0], Λ4[0]}} == {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {ω1[0], ω2[0], ω3[0]} == {0, 1, 0}}, {Λ1, Λ2, Λ3, Λ4, ω1, ω2, ω3}, {t, 0, 1}]
```